# upgrade ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 but packages remain +bionic1

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-20.04

after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 some package remain in +bionic1 version

```
sudo apt list | grep python3.8


WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

idle-python3.8/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 all
libpython3.8-dbg/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
libpython3.8-dbg/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
libpython3.8-dev/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
libpython3.8-dev/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
libpython3.8-minimal/now 3.8.2-1+bionic1 amd64 [installed,local]
libpython3.8-minimal/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
libpython3.8-stdlib/now 3.8.2-1+bionic1 amd64 [installed,local]
libpython3.8-stdlib/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
libpython3.8-testsuite/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 all
libpython3.8/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
libpython3.8/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
python3.8-dbg/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
python3.8-dbg/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
python3.8-dev/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
python3.8-dev/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
python3.8-doc/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 all
python3.8-examples/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 all
python3.8-minimal/now 3.8.2-1+bionic1 amd64 [installed,local]
python3.8-minimal/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
python3.8-venv/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
python3.8-venv/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
python3.8/now 3.8.2-1+bionic1 amd64 [installed,local]
python3.8/focal-updates,focal-security 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 i386
```

as you can see above `python3.8-minimal/now 3.8.2-1+bionic1 amd64 [installed,local]` remain in bionic version if I want to purge and install python3.8 then many dependency will removed too and this may cause break my OS how can I push ubuntu to switch all install +bionic1 package to focal version `ubuntu1.1` or `ubuntu1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ultimately, the maintainers probably need to make an upstream patch to the Python packages as the version/epoch parser apparently believes the prefix `-1+bionic1` to be newer than `-1ubuntu1.1`.

In my case, the `-1+bionic1` prefix for Python 3.8 came from installing Python 3.8 packages from the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and not from the canonical repositories.

That said, I was able to force a "downgrade" to the correct Ubuntu-Focal packages using this command:

```
sudo apt install libpython3.8:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 libpython3.8-dev:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 libpython3.8-minimal:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 python3.8=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1 python3.8-minimal=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1
```

I ran into this issue trying to install other Python libraries like `python3-venv` after an 18.04->20.04 system upgrade and these packages pinned their dependencies to the `3.8.2-1ubuntu1.1` version.

Comment: to get the package name, use the command: `apt-cache showpkg python3.8`, which shows me the suffix name `3.8.2-1ubuntu1` instead.

Answer (score 6):

i was having similar issue while installing vim after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. combining pztrick answer and oon arfiandwi comment on accepted answer worked for me

```
sudo apt install libpython3.8:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 libpython3.8-dev:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 libpython3.8-minimal:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 python3.8=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 python3.8-minimal=3.8.2-1ubuntu1
```

Answer (score 0):

After running
`apt --fix-broken install`
I can install vim.