# Can't install python3-venv in Ubuntu 20.04, some broken packages

Tags: python, ubuntu

*This might be long but please bear with me till the end*

When I tried to install python3-venv while following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart)

```bash
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
```

It threw the following error:

```
libffi-dev python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.3-4).
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1.1).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So instead of `python3-dev`, I tried `python3` only and it ran.

After that, I ran this command:

```bash
sudo apt install -y python3-venv
```

Then it gave me this:

```bash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-venv : Depends: python3.8-venv (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I thought maybe I need to install `python3.8-venv`, so I did:

```bash
sudo apt install -y python3.8-venv
```

AND, it gave me this error:

```bash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5) but 3.8.13-1+bionic2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

THEN, I tried:

```bash
sudo apt install -y python3.8
```

which was fine and gave me this

```bash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.13-1+bionic2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

I don't know what to do, my virtual env isn't working, I read somewhere that it's pre-installed so I also tried directly creating a virtual env with

```bash
python3 -m venv myEnv
```

Which again gave me this:

```bash
Error: Command '['/home/yash/Desktop/DashMed/myEnv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

which upon googling said to install python3-venv which I've already failed in

SO I AM STUCK IN THIS LOOP

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for these issues was the version of python3.8

I had version `3.8.13-1+bionic2` but we needed `3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.5`

I think this generally occurs when you upgrade from *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS* to *Ubuntu 20.04 LTS* using in-built *Software & Updates*

So I found this command which rolled back the versions now everything works fine

```bash
sudo apt install libpython3.8:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 libpython3.8-dev:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 libpython3.8-minimal:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 python3.8=3.8.2-1ubuntu1 python3.8-minimal=3.8.2-1ubuntu1
```

After this, all those other commands ran perfectly on my system

I found this rollback command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703923/14319138)